# Coprime numbers (3, n)=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading a proof for a problem related to groups, where originally n=3k for generators x,y and relations $x^n=1$,$y^2=1$, and $xy=yx^2$   and it stated the following: $$(3, n)=1 \rightarrow  n=3k+1$$ or $$n=3k+2$$

And thus, x=1 holds as a relation.

I understand how x=1 follows from n=3k+1 or n=3k+2=3(k+1)-1, but how does n=3k+1 or n=3k+2 follow from (3, n)=1?

Comment: There are only three possibilities mod 3 since n and 3 are relatively prime one is eliminated.

Comment: Well, what if n=3k+3, or 3k+4, or 3k+5, or 3k+6?